# Extracting difference between strings t-sql

Tags: sql-server, string, t-sql

How would I be able to extract the values 2011/01/01, 412 and 523 from @str1, knowing beforehand that it will have the format of @str2?

```
 declare @str1 varchar(100)
 declare @str2 varchar(100)
 set @str1 =  '2011/01/01 Creation of 412 Transactions and 523 Operations.'
 set @str2 = '{0} Creation of {1} Transactions and {2} Operations.'
```

Comment: Look at capturing groups in RegEx.

Comment: Yes, see my own answer. Looking for something different to solve this.

Comment: string functions vary from db platform to platform.  you need to tag you specific RDBMS, sql-server, oracle, mysql, etc?  I would assume sql-server looking at your code in which case you just need to look at CHARINDEX() and SUBSTRING()

Comment: Do we have a fixed number of parameters or at least a known maximum?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming SQL Server

**Edit:** I should add, if you can't use a UDF, it can easily migrated into the sub-query.

```
declare @str1 varchar(100) = '2011/01/01 Creation of 412 Transactions and 523 Operations.'
declare @str2 varchar(100) = '{0} Creation of {1} Transactions and {2} Operations.'

Select SeqNr = Row_Number() over (Order By A.RetSeq)-1
      ,Value = B.RetVal
  From (Select * from [dbo].[udf-Str-Parse](@str2,' ')) A
  Join (Select * from [dbo].[udf-Str-Parse](@str1,' ')) B
   on  A.RetSeq=B.RetSeq and A.RetVal Like '{%'
```

Returns

```
SeqNr   Value
0       2011/01/01
1       412
2       523
```

The UDF if needed

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[udf-Str-Parse] (@String varchar(max),@Delimiter varchar(10))
Returns Table 
As
Return (  
    Select RetSeq = Row_Number() over (Order By (Select null))
          ,RetVal = LTrim(RTrim(B.i.value('(./text())[1]', 'varchar(max)')))
    From (Select x = Cast('<x>'+ Replace(@String,@Delimiter,'</x><x>')+'</x>' as xml).query('.')) as A 
    Cross Apply x.nodes('x') AS B(i)
);
--Select * from [dbo].[udf-Str-Parse]('Dog,Cat,House,Car',',')
--Select * from [dbo].[udf-Str-Parse]('John Cappelletti was here',' ')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 SELECT
    TheDate = CAST(LEFT(@str1,CHARINDEX(' ',@str1)) AS DATE)
    ,Transactions = CAST(
          SUBSTRING(@str1
             ,CHARINDEX('Creation of ',@str1) + LEN('Creation of ')
             ,CHARINDEX(' Transactions',@str1) - CHARINDEX('Creation of ',@str1) - LEN('Creation of ')
          ) AS INT)
    ,Operations = CAST(
          SUBSTRING(@str1
             ,CHARINDEX('Transactions and ',@str1) + LEN('Transactions and ')
             ,CHARINDEX(' Operations',@str1) - CHARINDEX('Transactions and ',@str1) - LEN('Transactions and ')
          ) AS INT)
```

Comment: thanks Mat. I am now looking for a broader way to solve this issue covering different cases. split string difference seems to be working well.

Answer (score 0):

Not efficient but interesting way is replace "Creation of", "Transactions and" and "Operations." for xml elements tags, add tag on begining and use xquery (xpath) to qry xml. It could be very universal.

Or use patindex and substring functions for example into view:

```
create view vw_ParsedString
as
select
    str,
    substring(str, 1, 10) str_date,
    substring(str, 33, pidxToTran) str_trancnt,
    substring(str, pidxToTran + 17, pidxToOper) str_opercnt
from (
    select 
        str, 
        patindex('%Transactions and %', str) pidxToTran,
        patindex('%Operations.%', str) pidxToOper
    from tbl) pidx
```

10 is the length to end of date

33 is the length to first number

pidxToTran + 17 is the length to string + len of the string

This is very easy and effective, better than multiple use of scalar function. And when you compare with other script it is the most readable and shortest.